# What is the best way to implement a cut-generation problem in Gurobi?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I want to implement a cut in a MILP, which will be added, if we encounter a MIP-feasible point. The cut shall be implemented by a cut-generation problem. I want to bound the linear cut-expression(the parameters of which depend on the MIP-feasible point) from above by a minimal feasible RHS. Therefore, I want to maximize the cut-expression s.t. some box-constraints of the variables (see below).

`max sum(a[i]*x[i] for i in someIndexSet)`

`s.t. lb[i]<=x[i]<=ub[i]`

`x[i] continuous for all i in someIndexSet`

Looking into the Gurobi documentation I was thinking about using the callback facility. However, I was not sure, if we can call another Gurobi-instance from within the callback code, because I am not too sure how gurobi deals with the callback codes. So the question is: **Can we call Gurobi from within a callback code?**

We could solve the mentioned problem just by implementing a decision tree, which is quite cumbersome though. Therefore, I would like to call Gurobi from within that callback code.
Alternatively I could imagine stopping the optimization at that MIP-feasible point, calculating the constraint externally and then warm-starting the whole thing again. Intuitively, I would think there must be a better way, than the latter.

Comment: I would guess, from an implementation perspective, that this should work. Whatever is defining the callback would only need access to some pointer pointing to the other gurobi instance (generalizing). Your use-case looks even more simple, as this second instance could be created a-priori (pointer known) and re-used multiple times. This is just a guess and does not cover other potential problems like the battle for resources (during *dynamic search*, gurobi probably continues to work while your callback runs),potential need for synchronization (callbacks called from >1 theads) or license-restr.

Comment: Not sure if I am misreading what you are saying, but your `max sum(a[i]*x[i] for i in someIndexSet)` subject to `lb[i]<=x[i]<=ub[i]` can be solved by inspection (i.e. no need for a solver).

Comment: I am sorry for my imprecise statement, also I should have mentioned, that the x[i] are all continuous. What I meant was not by pure inspection, but I could write a small routine to solve that very special problem without using a proper solver considering coefficient signs and the variable ranges. Correct?

Comment: Yes, just look at the sign to decide whether to peg each variable at its lower or upper bound. "By inspection" is math speak for: "there is a trivial algorithm not worth spelling out"